# What is the best way to observe the progress of a file upload/download process?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, http, websocket

Given a Spring Boot REST API and an Angular Frontend, I am looking for a way to maintain an overview about the file upload/download progress.

I have come across [a good article](https://javaninja.io/angular-9-spring-boot-rest-api-file-upload-with-progress-bar/), which explains in detail how to implement this feature. From what I understand, the entire logic for this seems to be implemented in my client. It seems that I can set a property `reportProgress` in the HttpOptions of my POST request. When subscribing to the POST request, I am checking for a returned HttpEvent of type `UploadProgress`, which contains properties `loaded` and `total`.

Anyways. I was wondering:

1. Does the explained solution only work for file upload, or is there a similar way to watch the progress of a file download?
2. What is the idea behind this solution?

What do I mean by the second point?

In order to watch the progress of an upload/download process, my client needs to be informed by the server about how much data is has received/sent. Since my backend is a REST API, I will need to send an additional request asking "How much data have you received" or "How much data have you sent" every x seconds. At least that's my understanding of the REST API. Am I correct on this point? If so, how is this implemented in the above described method? Does Spring Boot constantly ask my server about how much data it has received?

Are there alternatives to this solution?

I am thinking about websockets: A websocket allows for bi-directional communication between my client and the server: The server should be able to just inform the client about the received amount of data without the client having to constantly ask about it. Would this be a better option, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Event reporting using the `reportProgress` will be the better option.
From my understanding, the actual requests will be sent to API only after the upload is completed. The event progress reporting is the feature of angular HttpClient.

Comment: What do you mean by `the actual requests will be sent to API only after the upload is completed`? I want to track the progress, i.e. I consider an upload, which takes time and I want to know how much longer it will take for the upload to be complete.